# Cant import project in Android studio(Could not find method compile() for arguments)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Sorry for my english. I cant understand why i cant import project to my android studio. I have file build gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

but i have error:

> Error:(9, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments
>   [com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>   Open
>   File

why its mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong **build.gradle** file.

In your top-level file you can't define an android block.

Just move this part inside the **module/build.gradle** file.

Comment: you are right, thanks! The problem was in one library